# Supremum and infimum of two different problems

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

So I want to calculate the supremum and infimum of

$\left\{\ln n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$

and

$\left\{\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{2n}\right)^n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$

separately.

For $\left\{\ln n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ I am thinking that I should use the derivative $\frac{1}{n}$ and when I put increasing values of $n$, it approaches zero. Is infimum 1 then as $\frac{1}{1}=1$? And does it not have a supremum?

For
$\left\{\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{2n}\right)^n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ I am thinking that I need to look at odd and even terms separately with Leibniz criterion. But I am very new to it and I don't exactly know how to approach it, and where I should start.

Comment: For the infimum $\ln n$ is an increasing function so the infimum is the first term and the supremum is the limit. For the second sequence, yes, try doing the even and odd terms separately, one is increasing and one is decreasing. Try plotting them.

Comment: But is infimum 1 because of the derivative or 0 because ln(1)=0? And then supremum is infinity?

Comment: The derivative doesn’t have anything to do with it except insofar as it tells you $\ln n$ is increasing. For example the infimum of the sequence $\{ 0,1,2,3... \}$ is also $0$.

Comment: Ah I see, I think I finally understand the concept, I just struggled with understanding what I exactly was supposed to look at.

Comment: For 2), are you  quite sure you need $\sup$, not limit?

Comment: @Alex the question I have states "What is supremum and infimum of the following series?"

Comment: Are you sure that the question used the word *series* rather than the word *sequence*.  The way that I was taught, given a sequence of #'s, the corresponding series represents the "running subtotals".  For example, given the **finite** sequence $\{1,2,3,4\}$, I was taught that the supremum of the sequence is $4$, while the supremum of the corresponding series is $10$.

Comment: @user2661923 it might as well be sequence, I am translating from another language so I am not sure D:

Comment: What about the *symbols* used in the original text?  I have seen the common convention that $\langle a_n\rangle$ refers to a sequence, while $\{a_n\}$ refers to a series.  **However,** although my *impression* is that the former symbolism is fairly standard, I'm not confident at all with my interpretation of the latter symbolism.

Comment: @user2661923 in the original text they use {}, and I don't really know, I managed to solve 1) at least.

Comment: Based on your last comment, it's probably not a good idea to try to draw a conclusion based on the symbol(s) used in the original text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1), one of the definitions of $\log$ is
$
\int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x} > \sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k} 
$
which is a diverging Harmonic series, so be comparison $\log $ diverges, hence $\limsup \log n =\infty$.

For 2), if you take $x_n = e^{\log x_n}$ (since $x_n>0$), you get (using Taylor series) that $x_n$ oscilates between $\liminf = e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ and $\limsup=e^{\frac{1}{2}}$. In this case $\lim$ means that for an arbitrarily $\varepsilon-$neighborhood $x_n$ will visit $L_{\sup}- \varepsilon$ and $L_{\inf}+\varepsilon$ infinite number of times.